# Writing filename to directory in utf-8

Tags: java, jsp, utf-8, filenames

I am having issues with the uploading files and saving their filenames correctly under UTF-8... I think I have done everything like setting up the charset and encoding in the html form and then also request.setCharacterEncoding("UTF8"), I am not sure why is still not working. 
My code is writing in HTML and JSP. 
Could you please help?
Many thanks

I am going to add a bit more of infomormation:

This line is the one I have managed to make it work, but it is not quite right, as the word gets cut off when the special character comes up.

```
saveFile = new String(saveFile.getBytes(), "UTF8");
```

The filename should be: **tríptico**.pdf but the results is **tr**

Answer (score 1):

Is saveFile a string? Why are you resetting it like that? Java string is already unicode, any UTF8 decoding must happen before text becomes java string.

Answer (score 1):

The code you have written can never work.

`saveFile.getBytes()` gets you bytes in the encoding defined by file.encoding, and then you are saying to Java, "assume that this byte array is UTF-8 and make it back into a string."

So, if file.encoding is UTF-8, this does nothing, and if it's something else, it will destroy your string.

What you need here is the right setting of file.encoding and then you won't need this extra stuff.

Answer (score 0):

You are not supposed to save the filenames as-is in UTF-8 unless the underlying filesystem supports UTF-8.  You should be receiving the filename, decoding it to Unicode, and then re-encoding it to whatever charset the filesystem actually uses.

Comment: Thanks for your reply Remy, but could you please elaborate a bit more?

Comment: There is no Java API for writing non-Unicode pathnames except -Dfile.encoding for the entire JVM.